# How can I prevent PerlTidy from aligning my assignments?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

By default, PerlTidy will line up assignments in my code. E.g.

PerlTidy changes this...

```
my $red = 1;
my $green = 2;
my $yellow = 3;
my $cyan = 4;
```

...into this...

```
my $red    = 1;
my $green  = 2;
my $yellow = 3;
my $cyan   = 4;
```

How do I prevent this from happening?
I've trawled the manual but I can't find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [How can I prevent PerlTidy from aligning assignments but keep adding single spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538209/how-can-i-prevent-perltidy-from-aligning-assignments-but-keep-adding-single-spac)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the discussion of the `-aws` option (`--add-whitespace`). By default `-aws` is enabled. You can alter this behavior using `-naws` (deleting whitespace is OK, but don't add) or `-fws` (don't add or delete whitespace). Details [here](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html#whitespace_control).

Comment: Thanks FM. -naws does roughly what I want. It won't un-align assignments that are already aligned, but such is life :)

Comment: Is it possible to keep addition of single spaces? I have just asked such a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538209/how-can-i-prevent-perltidy-from-aligning-assignments-but-keep-adding-single-space