# Perltidy Unalign assignment operators (= and =>)

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

I have code that was previous formatted by `perltidy`. It has assignment operators aligned. How can I get `perltidy` to unalign the assignment operators. I've been all over the manual, trying and experimenting. Here's my current argument list:

`-i=2 -nt -bt=2 -bbvt=0 -dws -asc -dsm -vt=2 -pt=2 -nwls='= =>' -wls='= =>' -sak='if elsif for while unless'`

Note, what I want is `-nwls='= =>' -wls='= =>'`, which is to say, delete all the whitespace left of the `=` or `=>` operators, but then add one space to the left. I'm figuring that what I really need to do is just write a script that runs `perltidy` twice to remove the whitespace around `=`, then add it again.

Comment: `=>` is not an assignment operator, it is the quoting comma.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the alignment you have and the alignment you want?

Comment: Maybe a patch like that one might help you: [How can I prevent PerlTidy from aligning assignments but keep adding single spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538209/how-can-i-prevent-perltidy-from-aligning-assignments-but-keep-adding-single-spac)

Comment: thanks for the correction eric, got anything useful to add though?

Comment: i think i'm siding with brian on this one. i saw that patch karsten, but i'm using a perltidy binary, not Perl::Tidy or whatever the module was, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Don't you realise that [`perltidy`](http://p3rl.org/perltidy) is just a very small wrapper script around the [`Perl::Tidy` module](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Tidy)? Both are part of the `Perl-Tidy` distribution.